# Scroll multiple nested recycleviews at once

Tags: java, android, nested, android-recyclerview, tablelayout

so... I came across a problem which I suspect there is no easy solution.

I need to make a big table in android, something like 20*10.
So I tried various ways to achieve that, Tablelayout got very quickly out of the question because it's inflating all the cells at once, which make the UI crash.

After a lot of search, I concluded that the best way is to use the reusable views concept.

So I came across a very nasty solution, with the use of nested recycleviews, here a diagram:

[image: A big recycleview with gridlayout vertical scroll with 2 columns, first is the static headers, and the second column is nested recycleview with linearlayout.]

> A big recycleview with gridlayout vertical scroll with 2 columns, first is the static headers, and the second column is nested recycleviews with linearlayout.

**My question is**, how to disable all the nested recycleviews scrollers, and implement one unified scroller (so it will look like one big table, and not separated rows).

And does this sounds like the best answer to this problem?

Any answer or guidance is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I actually found the answer myself, first of all I've used 
[stoyicker](https://github.com/stoyicker/AligningRecyclerView)
library for aligning recycleviews.

Then for the content recycler I made a LinearLayoutmanager with horizontal scrolling, and in his the adapter I made passed one item, which is a  nested Recycleview, with gridlayoutmanager with Vertical scrolling, disabled his touch events (the library can get buggy when the two recyclers can effect each other), and binded the left recycleviews scrolls to his.

And viola! I have the desired behavior.